# How to populate a generic container inside the class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to write a List (for a systems class project) that is going to be serialized through a socket connection.

The requirement specs says that a List should be serialized by writing an int for the length, then writing each element.

Also, there should be a (non-static) readFrom(InputStream in) method that reads in the data from a stream.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a generic WritableList object that takes  as a parameter, and populates itself when readFrom is called?

From what I know, you can't really get the type of the generic type inside the object without some hacky reflection. So I was thinking of passing the class as a parameter in the constructor like so

```
public class WritableList<E extends Writable> extends ArrayList<E> implements Writable {

    Class<E> storedClass;
    protected WritableList(Class<E> storedClass)
    {
        this.storedClass = storedClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFrom(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        int length = DataTypeIO.readInt(in);
        this.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            E e;
            try {
                e = storedClass.newInstance();
                e.readFrom(in);
                add(e);
            } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how to pass in a WritableList as a class now. When I try to instantiate it like so:

```
grid = new WritableList<WritableList<Location>>(**What goes here?**);
```

I'm not sure what kind of class to pass in. I'm not too experienced with java reflection, so any help here would be great. Thanks

Comment: can you please explain what you are looking for? the "what goes here" marker should have been fixed with Bozho's answer, but your rejection of the answer is quite confusing.

Comment: a new writable list takes a class<E>. Bozho's answer seems to suggest passing a new Writable list in the place of an argument that expects Class<E>, which I don't think quite works. Forgive me if this is confusing, but I'm not sure how to phrase it either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the design of this. It doesn't make sense to need to first instantiate the class using `.newInstance()` and then use that to call `.readFrom()`. `.newInstance()` is generally a bad sign when used in code, because it assumes the existence of a no-argument constructor (which does not exist in this case for your `WritableList` class), and even if it exists, it forces you to use the no-argument constructor, preventing one from passing data into the object.

Comment: That's probably true, and if I had designed the interface, I would have done it a different way. I'll accept this answer because I don't really see a good way of doing this anyways

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it should bew `new WritableList<Location>(Location.class)`

Comment: Problem is, I'm trying to populate the WritableList<WritableList<Location>, not the non-nested list.